# How to provide a very dynamic AppBar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar

I am trying to create a similar user experience as shown below for searching in a PDF document by dynamically controlling the AppBar.

I used a simple enum and StatefulWidget that rebuilds the AppBar elements according to different states. What I have is working but feels a bit flaky.

Has anyone got any suggestions for how I could build a better dynamic AppBar solution?

I have put a simplified version of my code below.

Thanks,

Luke

[image]

```dart
enum PdfAppBar { initial, search, searchComplete }

class ViewPdfScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ViewPdfScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ViewPdfScreen> createState() => _ViewPdfScreenState();
}

class _ViewPdfScreenState extends State<ViewPdfScreen> {
  PdfAppBar pdfAppBar = PdfAppBar.initial;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: _appBarLeading(),
          title: _appBarTitle(),
          centerTitle: pdfAppBar == PdfAppBar.initial,
          actions: _appBarActions(),
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: Text(
            'Test',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget? _appBarTitle() {
    if (pdfAppBar == PdfAppBar.search ||
        pdfAppBar == PdfAppBar.searchComplete) {
      return TextField(
        onSubmitted: (text) async {
          if (text.isNotEmpty) {
            print('search');
            setState(() {
              pdfAppBar = PdfAppBar.searchComplete;
            });
          }
        },
      );
    }
    return const Text('Article PDF');
  }

  Widget? _appBarLeading() {
    if (pdfAppBar == PdfAppBar.search ||
        pdfAppBar == PdfAppBar.searchComplete) {
      return IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            pdfAppBar = PdfAppBar.initial;
          });
        },
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.close_outlined,
        ),
      );
    }
    return null;
  }

  List<Widget>? _appBarActions() {
    if (pdfAppBar == PdfAppBar.searchComplete) {
      return [
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print('previous');
          },
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.chevron_left_outlined,
          ),
        ),
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print('next');
          },
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.navigate_next_outlined,
          ),
        ),
      ];
    }
    return [
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            pdfAppBar = PdfAppBar.search;
          });
        },
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.search_outlined,
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding @pskink. But I'm not sure how this would be materially different from using BlocBuilder?

Comment: so what kind of problems do you have with your `BlocBuilder`? could you post your current code?

Comment: I reverted to using a simple StatefulWidget and SetState. The code works but seems a bit flaky.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter provides the PreferredSize widget that allows you to build the AppBar UI however you like

[Flutter PreferredSize Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PreferredSize-class.html)

```dart
/// Flutter code sample for PreferredSize

// This sample shows a custom widget, similar to an [AppBar], which uses a
// [PreferredSize] widget, with its height set to 80 logical pixels.
// Changing the [PreferredSize] can be used to change the height
// of the custom app bar.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatelessWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class AppBarContent extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppBarContent({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text(
                'PreferredSize Sample',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              const Spacer(),
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  size: 20,
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.more_vert,
                  size: 20,
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateless widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(80.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: <Color>[Colors.blue, Colors.pink],
            ),
          ),
          child: const AppBarContent(),
        ),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Content'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding @Luis_RH. I did try a previous solution that used PreferredSize and swapped in different AppBars, but this seemed less flexible and left me thinking how to pass data between different AppBar instances. Maybe I'll keep it the way it is. It is working ;-)